# Duda respecto a MVVM C# - RaiseProperty

Tags: c#, mvvm

Estoy intentando comprender a fondo el tema de MVVM, y parte de sus métodos. He visto el método `RaiseProperty()` de dos formas diferentes y no entiendo cual es la diferencia.

Esta seria una:

```
    public void RaiseProperty([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {                       
    }
```

Y la otra directamente **no lleva** el `[CallerMemberName]`.

He estado leyendo sobre este `[CallerMemberName]` y dice que es para recibir el nombre del método que lo invoca.

Y una de mis dudas: **¿Para que saber el nombre del método que lo invoca?**

Después otra cosa que no comprendo bien es lo que incorpora, en este caso, el método `RaiseProperty` en mi ejercicio:

```
    public void RaiseProperty([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {            
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));            
    }
```

**¿Que esta haciendo el `?`, y para que se utiliza el `.Invoke()`?**

Comment: Esta pregunta son tres preguntas diferentes, deberías separar tus dudas en publicaciones distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos punto por punto

> ¿Para que saber el nombre del método que lo invoca?

Como se indica en la documentación, el atributo CallerMemberName permite evitar cadenas literales. Para enfocarlo en la arquitectura MVVM, es usual que una clase implemente la interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` del siguiente modo:

```
public class MiClase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string nombre;

   public string Nombre
   {
       get => nombre;
       set
       {
           if (value != nombre)
           {
               nombre = value;
               RaiseProperty("Nombre");
           }    
       }    
    }
}
```

Donde el método `RaiseProperty` está definido de manera similar a lo siguiente:

```
private void RaiseProperty(string nombrePropiedad)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nombrePropiedad));
}
```

Bueno, que pasa si luego quieres cambiar el nombre de la propiedad, digamos en vez de `Nombre` que sea `NombreCompleto`. El cambio no va a afectar a las cadenas literas como sucede dentro del *setter* de la propiedad, cuando es invocado el método: `RaiseProperty("Nombre");`, generando como consecuencia que el código no compile. 
Es por eso que se utiliza el atributo `CallerMemberName` para evitar el empleo de cadenas literales.

Sin embargo, el uso de dicho atributo en la arquitectura MVVM es ya algo obsoleto puesto que a partir de la versión 6.0 del lenguaje C# existe el operador `nameof` que permite obtener el nombre de las variables, métodos o tipos en tiempo de compilación. Luego, una implementación más actual de la interface INotifyPropertyChanged sería algo así como:

```
public class MiClase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string nombre;

   public string Nombre
   {
       get => nombre;
       set
       {
           if (value != nombre)
           {
               nombre = value;
               RaiseProperty(nameof(Nombre));
           }    
       }    
    }
}
```

Al referenciarse el nombre de la propiedad en lugar de emplear una cadena literal, los cambios de nombre ya no son un inconveniente.

> ¿Que esta haciendo el ?, y para que se utiliza el .Invoke()?

El símbolo `?.` es el *null conditional operator* y es un azúcar sintáctico que es válido a partir de C# 6.0 para evitar comparar un objecto con el valor `null` y funciona como el operador ternario `?:`. Supongamos que tenemos `A?.Metodo()`, si `A` es diferente de `null` entonces se invoca el método, es decir, `A.Metodo()`, pero si `A` es `null` entonces el resultado es `null` también.

Centrándonos en la implementación del método `RaiseProperty`, en lugar de hacer

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nombrePropiedad));
}
```

se hace uso del null conditional operator: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke()` de tal modo que el código resulte más compacto y sencillo de entender (esto último es discutible).
Finalmente, el método `Invoke` es un método que permite disparar eventos, como sucede en este caso en particular con el evento `PropertyChanged`.